# Power supply names

Tags: power-supply, schematics

I'm studying and trying to understand Google developer board schematics, but there are a lot of redundant power supplies. This board is a carrier board when SOM is mounted. For example this:

[image]

This is a dual DC-DC converter with 3.3V and 1.8V outputs, but in the design there are 1.8V and 3.3V that they are connected with power supplies from SOM:

[image]

This SOM datasheet shows this:

[image]

Connectors between SOM and board (outputs):

[image]

VDD_3V3 is not used.

[image]

What is the function of this? Does it supply more current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are power rails but not coming from separate power supplies. There's only one power supply which generates two separate voltages: BB_3V3 and BB_1V8. And all other 1V8 and 3V3 voltage rails are just copies (direct or filtered) of these rails.

The intention is to make the schematic more readable generally: If someone else is to look at the schematic, he/she can understand easily where a voltage is used at. In your case, V3V3 and V1V8 are used everywhere in the circuit. But BB_xxx voltages belong to only baseboard. So the designers might not have wanted to use BB_xx rail names everywhere in the circuit.

Look at VDDA_1V8, for example. This is not coming from a separate power supply. It's clear that this voltage is for ADC and probably copied (directly or filtered) from BB_1V8 line. Sometimes we do the same thing for easier readability:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSaWZg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### EDIT

One thing the OP missed is that 1V8 and 3V3 outputs of the SOM are labelled as **VDD_3V3** and **VDDA_1V8**, respectively (not V3V3 and V1V8), and VDD_3V3 and V3V3/BB_3V3 do not join together, likewise VDDA_1V8 and BB_1V8/V1V8 do not join either. There's only a single location where the OP may have confused: the supply line of RTL... IC. It looks like VDD_3V3 and V3V3 join but there's a 0R/DNP supply selector.

Comment: Checking SOM datasheet, the SOM supplies 1.8 and 3.3V outputs, that are connected with these BB supply tags.

Comment: @Juanma you missed something. I'm editing my answer so check back a few minutes later.

Comment: I have realised now, you are right. VDD_3V3 is used for nothing, I'm going to update the thread.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @Juanma apart from your confusion about joining rails, my thoughts still apply.

Comment: Sorry Rohat, I have another question, 3V3 and BB_3V3 are the same, but in enable pin 2 is used 3V3, how does this work? Is it posible that channel 2 doesn't work propertly if is enabled by the channel 1 output?

Comment: @Juanma `Is it posible that channel 2 doesn't work propertly if is enabled by the channel 1 output?` Well, It looks like the first buck regulator generates 3V3/BB_3V3, then its output is used as an enable signal for the 2nd buck which generates 1V8. This brings some sort of power sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you misunderstand what the red labels are.

All of the red "BB_1V8" labels are connected together with wires (we say they are the same *net*). All of the red "BB_3V3" labels are connected together with wires. And so on.

This is a way to avoid drawing really long wires all over the schematic. It has nothing to do with current - it's just a different way to draw the schematic.

Since there is a wire connecting a "BB_3V3" label and a "V3V3" label, this means all of those are really connected together like they're the same label i.e. they are both one big net. I can't say for sure why the designer used two different labels for the same net.

It is possible they wanted to keep things apart, for example by using BB_3V3 in one specific power supply module, and V3V3 in the rest of the circuit. Then, by drawing a line connecting together BB_3V3 and V3V3, they say that power supply module supplies the rest of the circuit. If they want to power the main circuit another way, they only need to change that one line on the schematic.